# How to get suggestion text from database for a MooTools auto-completer?

Tags: autocomplete, mootools

I need a textarea multi auto-completer like [this](http://digitarald.de/project/autocompleter/1-1/showcase/delicious-tags/).

However, in the example, the options are local. Does anyone know how I could get my options from a database?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply initialize the `tokens` array fetching all the values from the database. Be careful, this is good only if the number of words fetched fromm the database is not too big (hundreds, half a thousand maximum).

If it's not your case, and you have lots of words in your database, you have to think about an AJAX autocompleter solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I get hundreds of words from database!

Comment: I think that the "limit" should be around half a thousand. If you think you can reach more than this limit in your word table, then you have to use an AJAX-powered auto-completer script (like the one posted by Christoff).

Answer (score 0):

I've just released one since a lot of people seem to be after this kind of tagging (I blame google+) and I had it written and in my github repos already.

If you can work it out from the source as I have no time to document and support this, good luck: http://mootools.net/forge/p/mootagify

hint: you pass on the configured Request.JSON instance, which you setup to get the tags - the onSuccess event is handled by the `autoCompleter` class (which is a standalone).

github sources: https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/mooTagify/

Comment: Thanks! but I think I can't use it in my implementation, because I use Java and wicket framework. I see you have applied php!

Comment: this was just to mock the replies from the server. your replies for the tags could come from anything, java etc.